# Remove commas from regex using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know how to remove the commas when result is displayed on my website.

```js
let regex = /\W/g;
let string = "How are you today?";
let string2 = "48%"
let result = string.match(regex);
let result2 = string2.match(regex);

document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = result2;
```

```html
<p id="header"></p>
<p id="head"></p>
```

Comment: Do you have an example with a comma?

Comment: Yes it displays like this on my website ,,,?

Comment: Well the result of your match is `[' ', ' ', ' ', '?']` so what are you expecting??? You expecting to see whitespace in the HTML? What were you thinking you were going to see? You are setting innerHTML to an array which will use toString()

Comment: Because you're matching all the non word chars [\W](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_nonwordchar) so change to `\w`

Comment: Yes I was expecting to see whitespace in HTML.

Comment: `result.join('')` but your browser is most likely going to collapse all the spaces.

Comment: I want to display ? and % but when I display it there are 3 commas before the ?

Comment: Because you have an array. You are outputting the array.

Comment: Actually, @epascarello, `result.join('&nbsp');`

Comment: @danh There is whitespace, unclear why you would add more.

Comment: result.join('') worked thank you!

Comment: @epascarello - I guess I misunderstood the questioner's intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerHTML expects a string. You are setting it to an array. So the engine runs toString() on the array which returns all the indexes separated by a comma.

If you want to control how it is outputted, you need to use the join() method.

No character would be `result.join('')`